# solve Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT t.account_id,t.amount,t.customer_id,a.payment_id, a.payment_type_id,receipt_number,t.due_date FROM account_trxn t,account_payment a where a.account_id= '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and a.payment_id=t.payment_id and t.account_action_id=10"
    connection.Open()
    sCommand = New MySqlCommand(sql, connection)
    sAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(sCommand)
    sBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter)
    sDs = New DataSet()
    sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "form")
    sTable = sDs.Tables("form")
    connection.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables("form")
    DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True
    new_btn.Enabled = True
    save_btn.Enabled = True

    sAdapter.Update(sTable)
    DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
End Sub

 Private Sub save_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As         System.EventArgs) Handles new_btn.Click
    DataGridView1.[ReadOnly] = False
    save_btn.Enabled = True
    new_btn.Enabled = False
```

when i click on save button an error appear : Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables , i get that command builder can't generate if i select from multiple table but how can i solve the problem to edit and save on data grid view ?

Comment: Don't concatonate the variable in the sql string. Use parameters!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to perform an update on the data you just queried. Not sure why you are doing this but you can't and shouldn't.  The update is trying to generate the SQL needed to perform the update but is failing.  Remove this line:

```
sAdapter.Update(sTable)
```